Use Google Maps API within a chrome extension
Since manifest v3 doesn't allow the injection of a script directly into the popup.html In Chrome extensions,
How can I use the Google Maps API inside the extension UI as I can't include the script directly, Everything I want is to make the user enter his city name and I get the latitude and longitude then send it back to background.js using chrome.runtime.sendMessage
const initAutoComplete = () => {
    const input = document.getElementById("search") as HTMLInputElement;
    const autoComplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {
      types: ["(cities)"],
    });
    autoComplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
      const place = autoComplete.getPlace();
      if (!place.geometry) return;

      const latitude = place.geometry.location?.lat();
      const longitude = place.geometry.location?.lng();
      const city = place.address_components?.find(
        (component) => component.types[0] === "locality"
      )?.long_name;

      if (latitude && longitude && city) {
        setCity(city);
        setLatitude(parseFloat(latitude?.toString().slice(0, 9)));
        setLongitude(parseFloat(longitude?.toString().slice(0, 9)));
      }

    });
  };

 function loadScript() {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src =
      "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=apiKey&libraries=places";
    script.async = true;
    script.defer = true;
    script.onload = function () {
      initAutoComplete();
    };
    const scripts = document.head.getElementsByTagName("script");
    let exists = false;
    Object.values(scripts).forEach((scr) => {
      if (scr.src === script.src) exists = true;
    });
    if (!exists) document.head.appendChild(script);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    loadScript();
    initAutoComplete();
  }, []);

Tried this way but gives the same error:
Refused to load the script 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?....' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.


Do it inside the sandboxed iframe.
